# Meteor - swfobject.js + YouTube API

Tags: javascript, youtube, meteor, swfobject

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to get this (functioning) client side js code to work within meteor (theVideo variable is pulled out during a template event on an input element on the screen.)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>    
  <div id="ytapiplayer">
      You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  theVideo = 'tAbCgr6jJ_0';

  if(theVideo != 'null'){
        var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
        var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
        swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/"+theVideo+"?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
        "ytapiplayer", "325", "256", "8", null, null, params, atts);
  }

  function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
      ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
      ytplayer.playVideo();
    }
 </script>
```

Attempts to load the script by DOM injection (of this html/javascript) do not work, the swfobject script doesn't seem to load from both local and remote hosts.

Adding the script (swfobject.js) to my project root (the leaderboard example) causes a 'ReferenceError: window is not defined' when the app is launched (inside the terminal output).

This code works fine client side inside of a normal HTML page to load the script.

I found a [library](http://meteormodel.googlecode.com/svn-history/r92/trunk/METEOR/js/ext_new/build/widgets/chart/swfobject-min.js) in an ancient (2009) repo that didn't crash on startup, but then 'swfobject' not found errors popped up.

Any ideas on workarounds? Putting this code inside the a template event did not work either; loading the swfobject always seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

By placing the swfobject.js in the root directory it also gets parsed on the server where there isn't a `window` so this is why the error is being returned.

If you were to move it to `/client/lib` (also remove the first `var` on the first line of code under the comments otherwise it won't be scoped into the browser window.

Then you wouldn't have to reference the file manually you can have some HTML like:

```
<template name="video">
    <div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
    </div>
</template>
```

and some (client side) js:

```
 Template.video.rendered = function() {
     played = false; //prevent double plays on multiple renders
     theVideo = 'tAbCgr6jJ_0';
     if(theVideo != 'null' && !played){
         played = true
         var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
         var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
         swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/"+theVideo+"?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
    "ytapiplayer", "325", "256", "8", null, null, params, atts);

 }

 onYouTubePlayerReady = function  (playerId) {
    var ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    ytplayer.playVideo();
 }
```

I reformatted the onYouTubePlayerReady so that it can be accessed globally. I assume this is run by the script automatically? I didn't see references to it in your code.

Comment: that looks like it should work.. onYouTubePlayerReady function was some boiler plate code from the google youtube API reference. I'm not absolutely sure where it gets called either; but I'm guessing it is called after the HTML5 object gets the video and loads

Comment: Tried it out.. I was able to get the swf object in, but onYouTubePlayerReady function never executes, nor was I able to get the object via the dom (like the api instructions). Tried putting it in the callback function in the swfobject.. no luck..

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but I'm sure other people like me will stumble across this issue. These are just my notes.

The way I got swfobject to work in my project (to support clipboard copy) was to add the `<script>` code directly in the HTML iron-router template.

`<template name="writeApp">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
...`

In my .js code, I used my template.rendered function to set a globally available session variable called hasFlash:

`Template.writeApp.rendered = function() {
  Session.set('hasFlash', (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion('1') && true));
}`

Every time the page renders I can now see if the user has Flash now. On pages that need to display "Error: no flash" messaging, I have a helper function:

`Template.writeApp.helpers({
  hasFlash: function() {
    return Session.get('hasFlash');
  }
});`

in the HTML, I can use the hasFlash helper function to display the right message:

`{{#if hasFlash}}Copy to Clipboard {{else}} Needs Flash to Copy {{/if}}`

Hope this helps anyone who stumbled across this question